# How do you determine the look and feel of Qt Creator when compiling from source?

Tags: qt

I compiled Qt Creator from source and now it looks different from when I installed it via `apt-get`.

[image]

The folder icons used to be gray/tan colored, and the close tab button was previously a red X.

I recognize the current close icon as coming from somewhere else within my Linux Mint installation, so I'm pretty sure it's not coming from Qt. Is there a way to compile Qt Creator using the original Qt icons?

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_Look_for_Qt_and_GTK_Applications

It looks like there is a config tool for helping with this:

> ### Qt4 styles cand be changed in a similar way:
>
> Using the KDE4 System Settings (systemsettings), the settings can be found in Common Appearance and Behavior > Application Appearance > Style > Widget Style
>
> Using the command-line tool `$ kwriteconfig --file kdeglobals --group General --key widgetStyle [name of style]`.
>
> Using the Qt Configuration (**qtconfig-qt4**) application, the settings can be found in Appearance > Select GUI Style.

Hope that helps.